# How access Ajax generated source?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I created a php file that return dynamically generated text. This text is returned with a div id. When I retrieve that text using Ajax as responseText. I would like to access the properties of that div using javascript, which is impossible since that new text is not added to the DOM.

My question is, how can i access that div using either raw javascript or frameworks (am somewhat familiar with jQuery) ?

It may be useful to note that the div can be accessed using CSS.

Thank you.

Comment: my solution:

Make sure the javascript is executed AFTER the response is received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is a litte vague because you did not provided some your code but anyhow.

When you load response in DOM having html and javascript, javascript in it is never excecuted.

Solution would be one of the following

1. Load only html by AJAX not the Javascript itself, and after the html is loaded in to DOM execute the Javascript in the same ajax callback function.
2. If the Javascript is dynamically generated, try to make a generalized function out of it, load it in the html, and get json response including your html string and parameters for that function.
3. Get json/javascript response from your server and eval it when you receive it in callback function which i don't think is a good security measure.

Comment: @Rorchackh, if you can provide your code it will be easy for us to help you.

Comment: Hey Imran, The first solution is the one I did. It works perfectly. Thank you.